# Clear page/menus on menu change — php/AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have 3 select menus -- product, topic, and subtopic. Selecting all three will show the FAQ for what's been selected. That part is working fine. My problem is that, once all 3 have been selected and the FAQ shows, if the user goes back and chooses another product, the menus and text below remain there. I would like for them to disappear. I've tried $(.'div').hide() in a couple locations, to no avail. I'm a bit green when it comes to AJAX.  Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.box').hide();


            $('#product').on('change', function() {
                $('.box').hide();

                $('#'+$(this).val()).show();

            });     

            $('#topic').on('change', function() {  
                var sel = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "support_process.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {info : sel},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $( ".divtopic" ).html(data);
                    }
                });
            }); 

            $('body').on('change', '#subtopic', function(){
                var sel = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "subtopic_process.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {info : sel},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $( ".divsubtopic" ).html(data);
                    }
                });
            }); 

        });
```

And the html:

```
<div class="styled-select">
   <select id="product">
     <option value="option0">Select product...</option>
     <?php
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
      {
        $name = $row['name'];
        echo "<option value=\"option$count\">" . $name . "</option>";
        $count++;
      }
      ?>
   </select>
 </div>
<div id="option1" class="box"> 
      <div class="content">

      <?php
      $sql = mysqli_query($dbConnection, "SELECT t.id, t.topic FROM topic t JOIN product p ON p.id = t.p_id WHERE p.name='Hello'");
      ?>

      <div class="styled-select">
        <select name="topic" id="topic">
          <option value="optiont0" selected="selected">Select a topic for Hello...</option>
          <?php
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
          {
            echo "<option value=\"optiont$count\" name=\"topic[]\">" . $row['topic'] . "</option>";
            $count++;
          }

          ?>

        </select>
       </div> 
        <div class="divtopic"></div>

        <div class="divsubtopic">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

TIA for your help.

Comment: I don't see the `$(#product)` element in the HTML.

Comment: Added the product element.

Comment: Do you have any CSS rule like: `.box {display: whatelse !important;} `?

Comment: Have you tried to hide `.content` instead of `.box`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, @ManoloSalsas. Gave me lots to think about. I stepped away from it for a while, rethought things thru and decided to just add an empty string to the divs, i.e, $('.divtopic').html('') and $('.divsubtopic').html(''). That seems to work.

Comment: I recommend you to post your answer and accept it if your question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding an empty string to the necessary divs.

```
$('.divtopic').html('');
$('.divsubtopic').html('');
```

Did the trick. Now, when changing the topmost (product) select, the divs below clear. Maybe not the most efficient (???), but it works!